# Elasticsearch sorting with script

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, groovy

I'm trying to sort with the following script:

```
if (doc['stats.favoriteCount'].value > doc['stats.likeCount'].value)
{
    return doc['stats.favoriteCount'].value;
}

return doc['stats.likeCount'].value;
```

This is the request I'm using:

```
{
   "sort": [
      {
         "_script": {
            "script": {
               "file": "sorting-likes",
               "lang": "groovy"
            },
            "type": "number"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

And this is the error i'm getting:

```
"reason": {
   "type": "groovy_script_execution_exception",
   "reason": "failed to run file script [sorting-likes] using lang [groovy]",
   "caused_by": {
      "type": "missing_method_exception",
      "reason": "No signature of method: 7b6bb56cf8fda7e1301b150b05d81813258c223b.﻿if() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean, 7b6bb56cf8fda7e1301b150b05d81813258c223b$_run_closure1) values: [true, 7b6bb56cf8fda7e1301b150b05d81813258c223b$_run_closure1@63c6a777]\nPossible solutions: wait(), run(), run(), any(), find(), is(java.lang.Object)"
   }
}
```

I really can't see whats wrong. This used to be a longer script and I torn it down to the minimum I can use.

Running this code as inline works well:

```
{
   "sort": [
      {
         "_script": {
            "script": {
               "inline": "if (doc['stats.favoriteCount'].value>doc['stats.likeCount'].value)return doc['stats.favoriteCount'].value;return doc['stats.likeCount'].value;",
               "lang": "groovy"
            },
            "type": "number"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no idea why the original script didn't work, but this works well:

**query:**

```
"sort": [
  {
     "_script": {
        "script": {
           "file": "sorting",
           "params": {
               "param0": "stats.likeCount",
               "param1": "stats.favoriteCount",
               "param2": "",
               "param3": ""
           },
           "lang": "groovy"
        },
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc",
        "missing": 0
     }
  }
]
```

**script**

```
if (!param2)
    return max(doc[param0].value, doc[param1].value);

if (!param3)
    return max(doc[param0].value, max(doc[param1].value, doc[param2].value));

return max(doc[param0].value, max(doc[param1].value, max(doc[param2].value, doc[param3].value)));
```